# How do I add an icon inside a text_field_tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm using Rails 4 and Font Awesome (sass). I would like to add an icon to the left side of the search function, just like on Stack Overflow. This is my code for the search function.

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], placeholder: "Search..." %>
<% end %>
```

How would I go about to add:

```
<%= icon 'search' %>
```

into my text_field_tag so that I can also style the icon? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this, is to place the input and the icon together in a container ( `form` or `div` ) and use css to place the icon next to the search field and style to match.

quick gist http://sassmeister.com/gist/77508f4dccce9ced82c6

Comment: That is not rails!  You did not provide any answer. Just showing up a simple css file

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/) and [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label (:query) %>
   <div class="control has-icons-left">
     <%= f.text_field (:query), class: "input" %>
     <span class="icon is-small is-left">
       <i class="far fa-search"></i>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```